# How to get a pigeon to illustrate the pigeonhole principle?

Tags: tikz-pgf

I saw on the internet the following image, illustrating the [pigeonhole principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pigeonhole_principle):

[image]

Using TikZ, is it possible to make an image like that? I can only create the board, but I can't do the pigeon. Here is my MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw (0,0) rectangle (6,6);
\draw (0,2)--(6,2);
\draw (0,4)--(6,4);
\draw (2,0)--(0,6);
\draw (4,0)--(4,6);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Can't you just use an external image for the pigeon with `\includegraphics`? There doesn't seem much reason to do this bit in TikZ. (That is, if you don't like the Egyptian dove - my thought was also the hieroglyphs packages.)

Comment: Or you could use something like Inkscape to export TikZ code for the pigeon and turn it into a `pic`. (But the code does not tend to be very pretty or intelligible!)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
\documentclass[pstricks,margin=5mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pst-fun}
\begin{document}
\pspicture[dimen=m](12,12)
\multirput(0,0)(4,0){3}{\multirput(0,0)(0,4){3}{\psframe(4,4)\rput(0,1){\psBird}}}
\endpspicture
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: In what country or habitat do you see pigeons colored like that?

Comment: @murray: In PSTricks world. :-)

Answer (score 30):

There are some [hieroglyph packages](https://ctan.org/topic/font-archaic) for LaTeX, which define all kinds of symbols, e.g. ancient Egyptians walking around, dung beetles, or African birds.  Among these is the package [`phaistos`](https://ctan.org/pkg/phaistos) which defines `\HPdove`.  Strictly speaking it is a dove, but honestly, who can tell the difference from such a pictogram?

Thanks to @cfr for reminding me about ethics regarding animals in captivity.  I increased the spacing around the bird a little in the hope to meet the [legal standards](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Battery_cage#Legislation).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{phaistos}
\begin{document}
\renewcommand\arraystretch{2}
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|}
  \hline
  \PHdove & \PHdove & \PHdove \\
  \hline
  \PHdove & \PHdove & \PHdove \\
  \hline
  \PHdove & \PHdove & \PHdove \\
  \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

[image]

The Phaistos font is even available in OpenType and thus usable with Xe/LuaLaTeX.  For some reason the dove symbol is mirrored and smaller than in the Type 1 version.

What I find most convincing in this approach is that [Unicode actually defines this symbol](https://www.compart.com/en/unicode/U+101EF).  Therefore it is as easy as hitting the  key on your keyboard!

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\newfontfamily\phaistos{Phaistos}
%\def\PHdove{{\phaistos\symbol{"101EF}}}
\def\PHdove{{\phaistos }}
\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|}
  \hline
  \PHdove & \PHdove & \PHdove \\
  \hline
  \PHdove & \PHdove & \PHdove \\
  \hline
  \PHdove & \PHdove & \PHdove \\
  \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: (+1) The hieroglyphs packages have surprisingly useful things in them (surprising to me, that is). Could the type 1 dove get a little more head room, do you think? He or she looks most uncomfortable!

Comment: @cfr See updated answer.

Comment: That's much better - thank you!  (I can't vote again, unfortunately.)

Answer (score 21):

There are two doves (a peaceful and a Minoan one) in unicode:

```
% arara: lualatex

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}

\begin{document}
{\setmainfont{Symbola}
\symbol{"1F54A}%
\symbol{"101EF}}%
{\setmainfont{EversonMono}
\symbol{"101EF}}%
{\setmainfont{EversonMono-Bold}
\symbol{"101EF}}%
\end{document}
```

[image]

Please turn and order them as you please.

Comment: Maybe best not to set the document's main font to produce doves?

Comment: @cfr I have added some brackets. Typically, I would wrap those in custom command of course. But this is more a minimal-effort-answer to a minimal-effort-question.

Comment: Does that work? Interesting.

Comment: @cfr You mean the braces? They should. I hope.